# Need a hint on create jar using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

In spring-js.jar, there is a bunch of spring js files and css files compressed with dojo 1.5

Now I need to keep the spring js and css files but upgrade to dojo 1.6.

So here are two options:

1. create seperate jars, one holds spring js and the css files, the other holds the dojo 1.6, with same structure.
   or
2. put everything in one jar

I am a newbie on maven so any hints about maven build a jar file would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the 1.6 version in the pom. It should use that instead of the 1.5 coming in from the spring-js.jar.